# How can I update a element using SSJS in Xpages?

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

I have a button, In Button on click event has set of codes,

I want to update two particular element using Server side Javascript.

But these are in different tags...

I want to update an element using SSJS code.

I am using Lotu notes 8.5.2.

Comment: In CSJS, We have XSP.partialRefreshGet(id); Is their corresponding code for SSJS?

Comment: Get a copy of XPages cheat sheet, covers all the basics.  http://xpagescheatsheet.com/

Comment: I think My question was not clear... The thing is that I need to partial update for two separate panels within a single click event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check out this blog by Tim Tripcony, It will show you how to update two panels via partial refresh.

http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-84B6VP

basically the code for two refreshes looks like below.

XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:div3}", {
                    onComplete: function() {
                        XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:div4}");
                    }
                });

Answer (score 4):

You should update the datasource for the components and dont try to 'refresh' them. If you realy want to update their values you use

```
getComponent(x).setValue();
```

Another approach would be to just use the partialrefreshget()..